# Como adicionar barra de rolagem a um Scrollpane?

Tags: java, swing

Eu tenho um painel, e vou ter bastaste campos e botões nele. Pensei em usar um `JScrollPane` para não deixar a tela tão grande. Porém, não estou conseguindo adicionar essa barra de rolagem.

Como eu adiciono uma barra de rolagem dentro do painel `p`, no código de exemplo? Eu coloquei só um campo para simplificar o código.

```
package scroll;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TelaSroll extends JFrame {

    private final JTextField vazio = new JTextField();
    private JButton bt = new JButton("Exemplo");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelaSroll tela = new TelaSroll();
    }

    public TelaSroll() {
        setSize(450, 345);
        add(telaPainel());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent telaPainel() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();// Painel principal, nele eu adiciono outros paines que organizam a tela

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        p.add(vazio);
        vazio.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        JScrollPane srcPainel = new JScrollPane(p);
        painel.add(srcPainel);
        p.add(bt);
        return painel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o a barra de rolagem funcione, você não pode definir um tamanho fixo para o painel que adicionará ao `JScrollPane`, senão, durante a construção da tela, este tamanho é quem limitará os componentes dentro do `JScrollPane`. Ao invés disso, defina um tamanho preferido para o `JScrollPane`, para que a barra apareça automaticamente quando for necessário:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TelaSroll extends JFrame {

    private final JTextField vazio = new JTextField();
    private JButton bt = new JButton("Exemplo");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelaSroll tela = new TelaSroll();
    }

    public TelaSroll() {
        setSize(450, 345);
        add(telaPainel());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent telaPainel() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();// Painel principal, nele eu adiciono outros paines que organizam a tela

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        p.add(vazio);
        vazio.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        JScrollPane srcPainel = new JScrollPane(p);
        srcPainel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        painel.add(srcPainel);
        p.add(bt);
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            p.add(new JButton("botao-teste " + i));
        }
        return painel;
    }
}
```

No código acima, utilizei `BoxLayout` para demonstrar a barra vertical, mas caso o tamanho horizontal seja excedido, a barra horizontal também surgirá no componente.

Comment: usando outro gerenciador de layout ele buga um pouco, isso é porque eu não  estou definindo a posição do scroll (vertical/horizontal)?

Comment: @G.Araujo o que quer dizer com "buga um pouco"? Eu testei do jeito que o código estava inicialmente(sem o boxlayout), e o que ocorreu foi criar um scroll horizontal, já que todo JPanel tem por padrão o FlowLayout, que organiza componentes em forma de linha horizontal. Usei o boxlayout para exemplificar o scroll vertical, mas funciona pros dois.

Comment: deu certo  aqui, Obrigado !