# Criando componente dinamicamente

Tags: java, swing

Eu fiz um método cujo o objetivo é adicionar uma quantidade de checkBoxes de acordo com o valor de uma variável que eu vou receber. Queria que ele ficasse dentro de um scrollPane para que não ocupasse mais espaço do que eu defini.

O que eu não consegui foi fazer os componentes ficarem todos no mesmo `JScrollPane`. Queria fazer com que ficassem um ao lado do outro, com no máximo 4 checks em cada linha, então eu defini depois do for um tamanho pequeno para o `JScrollPane`, porem ele cria um JScrollPane para cada check.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TesteAdd extends JFrame {

    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();

    public TesteAdd() {
        add(addComp());
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent addComp() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        painel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Borda"));

        int controle = 7;

        for (int i = 0; i < controle; i++) {
            String nome = "Check " + Integer.toString(i);
            JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(nome);

            painel.add(jsp = new JScrollPane(box));
        }
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        painel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        return painel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TesteAdd a = new TesteAdd();
    }
}
```

Comment: `painel.add(jsp = new JScrollPane(box));` nao notou nada de errado aqui?

Comment: @diegofm sem ser desse jeito, eu não consegui fazer ele "pegar", ele ta adicionando um jsp pra cada ne? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você quer adicionar componentes comuns como botoes e checkboxes em um painel rolável, é preciso antes adicionar esses componentes em um painel comum e adicionar este painel como `ViewPort` do painel rolável. Seu código não funciona porque você tenta adicionar diretamente ao painel rolável.

Outro problema é que, devido ao layout padrão dos JPanels, mesmo fazendo da forma explicada, será gerado scroll horizontal, pois o [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) organiza cada componente ao lado do outro, horizontalmente. Como não podemos limitar o tamanho desse painel onde adicionaremos os checkboxes(veja o motivo [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/201799/28595)), teremos que utilizar nele outro layout que nos permita organizar itens em grupos com 4 em cada linha, o [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) permite esse modo de organização.

Você precisará criar mais um  `JPanel` no seu método `addComp`, e definir o `GridLayout` como layout dele:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4));
```

Os parâmetros do `GridLayout` são, respectivamente, o número de linhas e número de colunas. Como não temos a definição do total de linhas, passamos 0, que informa ao layout que é um número indefinido ainda, e colunas passamos 4 já que você quer organizar em linhas com esta quantidade.

Modifique seu laço para que os checkboxes sejam adicionados nesse novo painel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < controle; i++) {
    String nome = "Check " + Integer.toString(i);
    JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(nome);
    p.add(box);
}
```

Defina um tamanho para seu ScrollPane(pois é a partir deste tamanho é que ele se baseará para gerar as barras de rolagens) e defina o novo painel anterior como `ViewPort` desse scrollPane:

```
jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
jsp.setViewportView(p);
```

Agora basta adicionar o scrollpane ao painel que você vai retornar no método para o JFrame.

O código final fica:

```
private JComponent addComp() {
    JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    painel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Borda"));

    //neste painel é que adicionaremos os chekboxes
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4));

    int controle = 30;

    for (int i = 0; i < controle; i++) {
        String nome = "Check " + i;
        JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(nome);
        p.add(box);
    }
    //defini um tamanho preferido pro scrollpane
    jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 150));
    //defini o painel de checkboxes como viewport do scrollpane
    jsp.setViewportView(p);
    painel.add(jsp);
    return painel;
}
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um pequeno detalhe no seu código é utilizar `Integer.toString` pra converter um inteiro para String, e ele é desnecessário ali, pois quando você concatena um tipo primitivo a uma string, ele é convertido automaticamente para string. Por isso, modifiquei direto no seu método.

Se quiser aprender mais sobre este layout, segue o link da documentação oficial, com um pequeno tutorial de uso:

[How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: eu havia tentado assim, mais ai ele não adiciona nada na tela. for (int i = 0; i < controle; i++) {
            String nome = "Check " + Integer.toString(i);
            JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(nome);
            jsp.add(box);
        }
        painel.add(jsp);

Comment: @Java você fez as alterações conforme expliquei na resposta? Você vai alterar a linha que citei por `jsp.add(box);` isso dentro do laço. Você não vai adicionar o scrollpane ao painel dentro do laço.

Comment: sim, eu fiz, o que eu postei ai no comentário de cima foi justamente a alteração, depois do for, eu adiciono o jsp.    eu faço > painel.add(jsp); mais não é adicionado os checks.

Comment: @Java claro que adiciona, testei aqui e apareceu os 7 checks normalmente.

Comment: estranho aumentei ate o tamanho do painel, porém nada.

Comment: @Java você usa setpreferredsize mas sem pack ele é ignorado. Não é que o componente não é adicionado, é que o painel e o scroll sao iniciados com tamanho zero. Ou você usa preferredsize em toda a aplicação e da um pack() pros tamanhos serem respeitados, ou usa tamanho fixo em tudo, o que é uma pratica ruim, como fez com o jframe. `setSize` !=  `setPreferredsize`, é bom não misturar eles, a não ser que se tenha certeza de que é necessário.

Comment: mesmo fazendo setPreferredSize e usando o pack, ele ainda n exibe os check.

Comment: @Java achei o erro.

Comment: e o que é que causa ?

Comment: @Java tem a ver com vc adicionar direto no scrollpane. Amanhã respondo com mais calma explicando o problema, caso você não encontrei a solução.

Comment: eu fico no aguardo, não identifiquei o erro

Comment: @Java estava sem energia elétrica até agora, vou responder. Só não entendi porque alguém deu negativo, mas ta de boa.

Comment: negativo no que ?

Comment: @Java é que a resposta foi negativada por alguém, mas não importa, eu já atualizei a resposta explicando o problema e como resolver, da uma olhada ai :)

Comment: Ops! Agora que vi que você quer é organizar em linhas com 4, e não todos um abaixo do outro. A boa noticia é que só precisamos alterar o layout do painel p e tudo está resolvida :D